# Why is parseInt(021, 8) === 15?

Tags: javascript

In reviewing `parseInt(string, radix)` in: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

all `13` examples make perfect sense except for this one.

According to one example, `parseInt(015, 10)` will return `13`. This makes sense assuming that numericals that begin with 0 are treated as an octal, regardless of the `10` that appears in the radix position.

So if the octal is specified as it is in the question header:
`parseInt(021, 8)`

Then why wouldn't this be `17` (vs. `15` per the Mozilla documentation and in my tests in jsfiddle?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: If you read the first line of the MDN docs that you linked you can see that the first argument should be a string.

Comment: When you write a number (not a string) as `021` that is in octal notation. So when the engine parses your code, it parses that to be the number 17 (decimal). When you call parseInt, 17 is converted to the string "17" and then decoded as an octal number. 17 octal = 15 decimal. Change it to a string `"021"` and you get your expected result.

Comment: `parseInt(021,10) === parseInt(021) === 17`. The root of the issue was passing the "8" as the radix.

Comment: `parseInt(021, 8) === parseInt(017, 10) === 15`. (Because of the internal treatment of 021)

Comment: Javascript allows you to write the same number in decimal  `31`, hex `0x1F`, binary `0b11111` or octal `037`. There is also a new type: BigInt, `31n`.

Comment: Thank you @some, your answer was very clear!

Comment: @RichS No, the root of the issue was not passing `8` as the radix. If anything it was passing `021` as a number instead of a string. This is the point of the example.

Comment: parseInt(021) would have been 17 if he left the 8 out, even if the 021 were a number.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is because `0n` is [octal notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates#Octal_numbers) in javascript, just like `Oxn` is [hex notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates#Hexadecimal_numbers):

```js
console.log(021 === 0x11 && 021 === 17);
```

So what you wrote got evaluated as `parseInt(17, 8);`

Then this 17 number gets coerced to the string `"17"` and the result is 15.

```js
console.log(parseInt(17, 8))
```

Note that all this would not have happened in strict mode, where `0n` notation has been deprecated:

```js
(function(){
  "use strict";
  // Syntax Error
  console.log(parseInt(015, 8))
})();
```

Comment: This is the direct answer to the question asked. The input to parseInt *can* be a number, although it's *convention* (and highly recommend) to normally pass in a string.

Comment: Very good that you mentioned **strict mode**.

Comment: Why would you say that `015` is invalid as octal?

Comment: 015? Did you mean 018 or 019 etc?

Comment: Yes you guys are right dunno what I had in mind...

Comment: @RichS nobody on this answer had any doubt about what this function accepts (any type) and what it does to it (call toString). Maybe you want to comment on Gerardo's answer instead. Ps: It's not parseInt that doesn't accept octal notation...

Comment: It's also useful to note that `021` is treated as octal but `"021"` (_quoted_ form) as a decimal. So, `parseInt("021")` will output 21.

Answer (score 12):

The first argument of `parseInt` should be a **string**. The same [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) says:

> The value to parse. If the string argument is not a string, then it is converted to a string (using the ToString abstract operation).

You can see that this works as expected:

```js
console.log(parseInt("021", 8))
```

The problem in your tests is that you're using a number, not a string. When you use `021` as a number, as you already knows (when you said *"numericals that begin with 0 are treated as an octal"*), it gets converted to `"17"`:

```js
console.log(021.toString())
```

And that gives you the result you're seeing:

```js
console.log(parseInt("17", 8))
```

Comment: This is correct as per the first line of the MDN documentation.

Comment: I may be stating the obvious, but 021 is the *octet* representation. So, 021 = 0*8^2 + 2*8^1 + 1*8^0 = 0 + 16 + 1 = 17. It gets treated like an *octet* string because of the 0 padding. If you leave off the "0", then parseInt(21) returns 21, whereas parseInt(021) returns 17, *even if the input is already a number and **not** a string.

Answer (score 4):

When you type `021` then this is valid octal number and because prefix `0` JS convert it to decimal `17`. But if you type not valid octal number e.g. 019 then JS will NOT convert it but treat as decimal

```js
console.log(021)    // octal
console.log(019)    // not octal

if( 021 < 019 ) console.log('Paradox');
```

Comment: Technically is correct, since `9` is not part of the octal system the runtime considers it as decimal